# "A type named 'Product' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type." in D365

Tags: odata, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I am trying to update the Product entity and getting the following error

> "internalexception":{ "message":"A type named 'Product' could not be
>   resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must
>   resolve to a valid
>   type.","type":"System.InvalidOperationException","stacktrace":" at
>   Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.AxODataEntityDeserializer.ReadODataBody[T](HttpRequestMessage
>   request)" }

I have used OData Connected Service in VS2017 to generate the proxy class and trying to update by calling these resources and following is the code for updating the entity record

```
DataServiceCollection<Product> products = new DataServiceCollection<Product>(context.ODataResources, "Products", null, null);

       products.Add(product); //here product is the entity object that needs to be updated.

       var productTobeUpdated = products.FirstOrDefault();

       productTobeUpdated.property = value;

       context.ODataResources.UpdateObject(productTobeUpdated);

       _context.ODataResources.SaveChangesAsync(SaveChangesOptions.PostOnlySetProperties)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How are you trying? Can you show your code? Maybe you should read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Vic: I have added the code that I am using

Comment: Which entity exactly are you using? Which version of D365FO? You are omitting important details...

Comment: I am using a custom entity and the D365FO version is 7.2

Comment: If you are using a custom entity, maybe the issue is related to it. It is hard to say, since without all the code it is not possible to reproduce your problem. Moreover consider that the version of D365FO that you are using is quite old.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to update the entity using DataServiceCollection in this case of connected service?